# Is it possible to derive the probit model by writing it in exponential family form?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, exponential-family, probit

We always use  latent variable approach to derive probit model,
[image]

is there any way to derive probit model from the exponential family form (by using link function)?

Also, does logit-normal distribution has relationship with probit model?

Thank you!

Comment: If one introduces the latent Normal variable $Y^*$ in the model, the joint model is an exponential family.

Comment: So there is no need to derive the link function if we use latent variable approach...?

Comment: I do not understand, both representation are equivalent.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I mean how can we transform the natural parameter to cdf of normal...? I think it is so confused...